# Flexbox child collapsed after aligning

Tags: css, flexbox

Can't figure out how to keep the child items same height on both sides after aligning their content to the middle.

My aim is to create a layout as seen in picture:
[image]

```
  <div class="halves">
<div class="half">
   <div class="half-inner is-right">H1</div>
</div>    
<div class="half">
  <div class="half-inner is-left">H2
  <br> asdfs df <br>a sdfadsf sdfa dadsf df asdf afdf sadf asdf  </div>
</div>
```

```
.halves{
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid red;  
  .half{
    flex: 1;
    border: 10px solid yellow;
    /* align-items: center; */
    display: flex;    

    .half-inner{
      max-width: 100px;


      &.is-right{
        margin-left: auto;
        background: pink;
      }      
      &.is-left{
        background: green;
      }

    }
  }
}
```

My current code here: http://codepen.io/zsitro/pen/YqpLba
In my example uncommenting `/* align-items: center; */` you can see the child item collapses.

I appreciate any guidance. ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`align-items: center` forces the div into the center of a flex container, and in the event of no specific declarations of width/height/flex-basis/whatnot, it makes the div as big as its content, preserving the whitespace. If you want the div to stretch, you will need the the `align-items` value to be `stretch` so it takes up the entire height of the parent container.

Additionally, if you want the `.half-inner` divs to be equal in width: `flex: 1` (or `flex-grow: 1`) is a child property, so the declaration you currently have only applies to the `.half` divs, not the `.half-inner` divs. Since the parent `.half` div is a flex container, you can just add `flex:1` under the `.half-inner` CSS and you should be good to go.

```
.halves{
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid red;  
  .half{
    flex: 1;
    border: 10px solid yellow;
     align-items: stretch; 
    display: flex;    

    .half-inner{
      max-width: 100px;
      flex: 1;

      &.is-right{
        margin-left: auto;
        background: pink;
      }      
      &.is-left{
        background: green;
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it helps indeed, only the inner text content is still not vertically centered within the half-inner. That's where I struggle.

Comment: Vertical centering in flexbox can be very tricky, as `vertical-align` does not work. You could wrap the text inside in a `span` tag and make the `.half-inner` div a flex container. Then for absolute centering you could set `align-items`, `justify-content` and `text-align` to `center`, or you could give the `span` a `margin: auto` and `text-align: center`.

Comment: @zsitro Yes, that looks great.